# Could not set unknown property 'useAndroidX' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension

Tags: android, androidx

I want to add a library that i've found on github but it required androidx.I found out that i should put these:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

here

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kolydas.greeksinbrno"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true

}
```

But i got this error

> Could not set unknown property 'useAndroidX' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Those two properties need to be defined in a `gradle.properties` file at the root of your project, not in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Incase you wanted a link to google dev official instructions, https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

Comment: What about `viewBinding` library?