# Android error "Could not set unknown property 'useAndroidX' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension"

Tags: android

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have used the above dependencies and I'm getting this error even though I've migrated to AndroidX

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> Could not set unknown property 'useAndroidX' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857213/7765316) answer

Those two properties need to be defined in the [gradle.properties](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#properties-files) file at the root of your project, not in your app level build.gradle.

Comment: android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true ...Should I still add my dependencies of support libraries after enabling AndroidX and Jetifier true and migrating to AndroidX

Comment: No need for those support libraries, With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.- [ref](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). If you try this, All dependencies will be automatically changed to AndroidX compatible. and you can use `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'` `implementation  'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13'` for giving legacy support. But most of time no need for those support libries.

Comment: See [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings) for normal and AndroidX mapping libraries.